# Efficient way to insert multiple rows and assigning each one's Id to another table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the scenario:

I have table `Request(RId)`, table `Service(SId)` and table `Mapping(MId)`.

Now first a request is generated into a Request table. Then its related n number of service is created. Suppose there are 5 services for 1 request. Now there is a mapping table which maintain relationship between table Request and table Service.

**Mapping Table Example:**

```
MId | RId | SId
----------------
 1  |  1  |  2
 2  |  1  |  3  
 3  |  1  |  4
 4  |  2  |  5
 5  |  2  |  6
 6  |  3  |  8
```

Now, I have two way to do this:

**1st pass**: insert one service to SP in DB, do insertion and then get its Id and make entry in `Mapping` table. Means if I have 5 services, I have to go in the backend 5 times.(Insertion of service and in mapping in single SP)(Which is currently I am using).

**2nd pass**: all service data to SP as TableType and insert into DB and get last 5 services Id and perform all entry into Mapping table through while loop. Means I have to go in the backend only once, but if any other person has inserted service for his/her request, I will get wrong Ids and will do mapping wrongly.

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause to capture identities from multiple inserted rows. In the following, I'm assuming that `ServiceName` and `RequestName` are sufficient to uniquely identify values being passed in. If they're not, then hopefully you can adapt the below (you didn't really define in the question any usable non-identity column names or values):

First, set up the tables:

```
create table Requests (RId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,RequestName varchar(10) not null)
create table Services (SId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null primary key,ServiceName varchar(10) not null)
create table Mappings (MId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,RId int not null references Requests,SId int not null references Services)
```

Now declare what would be the [TVP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489.aspx) passed into the stored procedure (note that this script and the next need to be run together in this simulation):

```
declare @NewValues table (
    RequestName varchar(10) not null,
    ServiceName varchar(10) not null
)
insert into @NewValues (RequestName,ServiceName) values
('R1','S1'),
('R1','S2'),
('R1','S3'),
('R2','S4'),
('R2','S5'),
('R3','S6')
```

And then, inside the SP, you'd have code like the following:

```
declare @TmpRIDs table (RequestName varchar(10) not null,RId int not null)
declare @TmpSIDs table (ServiceName varchar(10) not null,SId int not null)

;merge into Requests r using (select distinct RequestName from @NewValues) n on 1=0
when not matched then insert (RequestName) values (n.RequestName)
output n.RequestName,inserted.RId into @TmpRIDs;

;merge into Services s using (select distinct ServiceName from @NewValues) n on 1=0
when not matched then insert (ServiceName) values (n.ServiceName)
output n.ServiceName,inserted.SId into @TmpSIDs;

insert into Mappings (RId,SId)
select RId,SId
from @NewValues nv
    inner join
    @TmpRIds r
        on
            nv.RequestName = r.RequestName 
    inner join
    @TmpSIDs s
        on
            nv.ServiceName = s.ServiceName;
```

And to check the result:

```
select * from Mappings
```

produces:

```
MId         RId         SId
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           1           3
4           2           4
5           2           5
6           3           6
```

Which is similar to what you have in your question.

The tricky part of the code is (*mis-*)using the `MERGE` statement, in order to be able to capture columns from both the `inserted` table (which contains the newly generated `IDENTITY` values) and the table that's acting as the source of rows. The `OUTPUT` clause for the `INSERT` statement *only* allows reference to the `inserted` pseudo-table, so it can't be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You second propose is not the way to go **definitely**.

I suppose you should make each insert in single transaction (maybe in a single procedure). If your Ids are identity you can use [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) to get the last inserted values and insert them in mapping table.

```
BEGIN TRAN
  DECLARE @ID1 numeric, @ID2 numeric    
  INSERT INTO Request values (//insert values
  SET @ID1=(SELECT @@IDENTITY)
  INSERT INTO Service values (//insert values
  SET @ID2=(SELECT @@IDENTITY)
  INSERT INTO Mapping values (@ID1,@ID2);
COMMIT TRAN
```

Otherwise you can use  *SELECT MAX(ID) WITH(UPDLOCK)* which will pervent your table from inserting other records while your transaction would not finish.

```
BEGIN TRAN
  DECLARE @ID1 numeric, @ID2 numeric      
  SET @ID2=(SELECT max(SId)+1 FROM Service WITH(UPDLOCK))
  INSERT INTO Request values (@ID1,//other values
  INSERT INTO Service values (@ID2,//other values
  INSERT INTO Mapping values ((SELECT max(MId)+1 FROM Mapping),@ID1,@ID2);
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: I am using @@Identity in my 1st Proc. So there is no way better than the 1st one. right?

Comment: @TechAddict Yes, after inserts in Request and Service you get @@IDENTITY values and use them in your Mapping insert

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)